# How to assign pandas column to other column, or default value if nan?

Tags: python, pandas

I have

`df`=

```
a
1
nan
3
```

I want some syntax for

`df["b"] = df["a"] or 5`

to create

```
a     b
1     1
nan   5
3     3
```

Does pandas support something like this?

BONUS:

what about different default values per index/group/anything?

Comment: This is covered in the fifth header under the "getting started" section of the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html#getting-started

Comment: @PaulH I am guessing you searched somehow... even what you sent is very long, and I couldn't find what I am looking for there. How are you searching the docs?

Comment: Navigate to pandas.pydata.org, click "documentation", click "getting started", read section headers

Comment: @PaulH the solution https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html was not visible to me where you pointed. I'll stick to google.

Comment: OK. that's fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, np.nan, 3]})
df["b"] = df["a"].fillna(5)
print(df)
```

> ```
>      a    b
> 0  1.0  1.0
> 1  NaN  5.0
> 2  3.0  3.0
> ```

digging through [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) gave the standard pandas solution. No need to go through numpy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where`

```
df['b'] = np.where(df['a'].isna(), 5, df['a'])
print(df)

     a    b
0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  5.0
2  3.0  3.0
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use `applymap()` function or even `factorize()` function for this.